# How to get a sessionId- dialogflow

Tags: node.js, session, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, api-ai

I am trying to get sessionId from response object but is that an efficient way or are there any other possibilities to get the session Id or sessions object?

For example: 
`request.body.session`: `projects/coffee-shop/agent/sessions/e6eb1812-9c3f-23fa-b590-f1656ee9a56e`

How to get exact **ID**:`e6eb1812-9c3f-23fa-b590-f1656ee9a56e` instead of path.
or How to get the **sessions object** in the path `projects/coffee-shop/agent/**sessions**/e6eb1812-9c3f-23fa-b590-f1656ee9a56e`

Comment: show us your code how are you doing it, then only we can tell

Comment: Sorry i cant show you entire code but this is how i am trying to access session: request.body.session gives me this  'projects/coffe-shop/agent/sessions/e6eb1812-9c3f-23fa-b590-f1656ee9a56e'. so this would be the sesson id: e6eb1812-9c3f-23fa-b590-f1656ee9a56e but its wierd that we have to parse this string to get session id.

Comment: Why can't you just keep the whole string? It's a bit convoluted but it does have the unique identifier you want

Comment: where ever I search for how to get a session Id no one has a clean way to get it so just trying because the application we are trying to do need just the session Id, not the whole string. there must be someway!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can grab the session id off the agent instance of WebhookClient:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);

    let sessionId = agent.session;
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
  });
```

Comment: Yes, this works same it returns the path, not the exact Id I was looking for.

Comment: You might want to update your question and be more specific

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have request object in variable `req`, we can use below python code:

```
session_path = req['session']
```

> it will print session object path:
>   projects/coffee-shop/agent/sessions/e6eb1812-9c3f-23fa-b590-f1656ee9a56e

to get the exact id, you can just split it with `/` and take the last element of the list

```
session = req['session'].split('/')[-1]
```

> it will print exact session id:
>   e6eb1812-9c3f-23fa-b590-f1656ee9a56e